# How to sort Properties in java?

Tags: java, sorting, properties

I have a `Properties` object and sometimes I need to add other `Properties` to it.

```
Properties myBasicProps = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(MY_PROPS_PATH);
...
Properties otherProps = new Properties();
otherProps.load(new StringReader(tempPropsString)); //tempPropsString contains my temporary properties
myBasicProps.putAll(otherProps);
```

I want to sort `myBasicProps` after this. I don't want to get all keys and values, sort them with `Collections.sort()` and then put it all to a new object. Is there a better way?

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html

Comment: @Thillakan i pasted the same link but deleted it after reading "I don't want to get all keys and values, sort them with Collections.sort()..."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, `java.util.Properties` extends `java.util.Hashtable` which doesn't define a predictable sort order for keys or values.

You could try dumping all values into something like `java.util.TreeMap`, which will impose a natural ordering on your keys.

Comment: This will mean upper case first and then lower case.

Answer (score 22):

all you have to do is create class which extends Properties.
   source: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/SortPropertieswhensaving.htm)

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SortedProperties sp = new SortedProperties();
    sp.put("B", "value B");
    sp.put("C", "value C");
    sp.put("A", "value A");
    sp.put("D", "value D");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sp.props");
    sp.store(fos, "sorted props");
  }

}
class SortedProperties extends Properties {
  public Enumeration keys() {
     Enumeration keysEnum = super.keys();
     Vector<String> keyList = new Vector<String>();
     while(keysEnum.hasMoreElements()){
       keyList.add((String)keysEnum.nextElement());
     }
     Collections.sort(keyList);
     return keyList.elements();
  }

}
```

it works for me.

Comment: Java 8 version: ArrayList<Object> result = Collections.list(super.keys());
Collections.sort(result, (a, b) -> a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));

return Collections.enumeration(result);

Comment: This does not work on `java >=9` . E.g. when using `BB`,`CC`.`AA`,`DD` for keys. See my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957344/1555615) below.

Answer (score 14):

Overriding `keys` works well with *Java 8*, but since *Java 9*, the new implementation of method `store` don't call the method `keys` any more but the method `entrySet`.

So, you have to override `entrySet` too to make your `Properties` sorted with *Java 8/9/10* when stored.

Here an example with inline overriding:

```
Properties properties = new Properties() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Set<Object> keySet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {

        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> set1 = super.entrySet();
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>(set1.size());

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> iterator = set1.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(java.util.Map.Entry<Object, Object> o1, java.util.Map.Entry<Object, Object> o2) {
                return o1.getKey().toString().compareTo(o2.getKey().toString());
            }
        }).iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
            set2.add(iterator.next());

        return set2;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        return Collections.enumeration(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 10):

**Solution working also for java > 8**

Despite the fact that the question does not explicitly mention about `store(OutputStream out, String comments)` functionality, I find this (and `load(InputStream inStream)` respectively) to be the most interesting part of `Properties`.

If we were not interested in **storing/loading properties** we could just replace `Properties` with some `Map` or `SortedMap` implementation.

The difference in `Properties` compared to `Map` is the existence of  `store()`/`load()` methods which offer some **specific serialization rules**. These rules have not (and will not) change across java versions. e.g.

- Storing pairs like `prop=value`
- Escaping rules for unicode and special characters.
- Adding optional comment on top

Unfortunately the **above 3 parts** of the functionality **are hidden** inside private methods, and **cannot be easily re-used** inside extended or alternative implementations that wish to use different internal data-structures (e.g. for keeping properties sorted).

So what remains is to **keep the same internal structures  and override the two `store()` methods**.

Note: For getting sorted properties, some time ago I followed [danisupr4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2742330/danisupr4) implementation, but on **java9 it broke.**

#### TL;DR

The code below **maintains the full functionality** of `Properties` by overriding only `store(OutputStream out, String comments)` method, and is **tested with all versions from `java5` - `java12`**.
I believe that filtering the output of this public method makes the implementation **less fragile** to future code changes in `java.util.Properties` class.

```java
    class SortedStoreProperties extends Properties {
    
        @Override
        public void store(OutputStream out, String comments) throws IOException {
            Properties sortedProps = new Properties() {
                @Override
                public Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {
                    /*
                     * Using comparator to avoid the following exception on jdk >=9: 
                     * java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$MapEntry cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Comparable
                     */
                    Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Map.Entry<Object, Object> o1, Map.Entry<Object, Object> o2) {
                            return o1.getKey().toString().compareTo(o2.getKey().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    );
                    sortedSet.addAll(super.entrySet());
                    return sortedSet;
                }
    
                @Override
                public Set<Object> keySet() {
                    return new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet());
                }
    
                @Override
                public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
                    return Collections.enumeration(new TreeSet<Object>(super.keySet()));
                }
    
            };
            sortedProps.putAll(this);
            sortedProps.store(out, comments);
        }
    }
```

Note: Depending on who calls the `store()`, it might be even better, to not override the existing method but create a new one: e.g. `storeSorted()`.

#### NOTE:

**For simplicity I override only one of the two `store()` methods but the same concept applies to both.**

Answer (score 6):

**@danisupr4 has the best solution.**

I would improve on it slightly so you won't receive any warnings in your IDE:

```
public static class MyProperties extends Properties {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        Enumeration<Object> keysEnum = super.keys();
        Vector<Object> keyList = new Vector<Object>();

        while (keysEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            keyList.add(keysEnum.nextElement());
        }

        Collections.sort(keyList, new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
            }
        });

        return keyList.elements();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

TreeMap should be the simplest way:

```
Properties myProps = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream(MY_PROPS_PATH);

try {
    myProps.load(new FileInputStream(extraPropertiesFilename));
        //you can load more properties from external file

    Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap(myProps);

    //output sorted properties (key=value)
    for (String key : sortedMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + "=" + sortedMap.get(key));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it much simpler to just sort the keys:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>()
for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
  keys.add(key)
}

Collections.sort(keys);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 `Properties.keys()` was used for storing the properties , in Java 9 this changed and `Properties.entrySet()` was used:

**Java 8**

```
private void store0(BufferedWriter bw, String comments, boolean escUnicode)
    throws IOException
{
...
        for (Enumeration<?> e = keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
```

**Java 9**

```
private void store0(BufferedWriter bw, String comments, boolean escUnicode)
    throws IOException
{
...
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : entrySet()) {
```

I use this class to handle both java version:

```
public class SortedProperties extends Properties {

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param unsortedProperties
     */
    public SortedProperties(Properties unsortedProperties) {
        putAll(unsortedProperties);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public synchronized Enumeration keys() {
        Enumeration<Object> keysEnum = super.keys();
        Vector<String> keyList = new Vector<String>();
        while (keysEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            keyList.add((String) keysEnum.nextElement());
        }
        Collections.sort(keyList);
        return keyList.elements();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet() {
        // use a TreeMap since in java 9 entrySet() instead of keys() is used in store()
        TreeMap<Object, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = super.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : entrySet) {
            treeMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return Collections.synchronizedSet(treeMap.entrySet());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can override keys() method for save sorted properties in txt file:

```
//this method downloaded from edu.umd.cs.findbugs.config package
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
    Set<?> set = keySet();
    return (Enumeration<Object>) sortKeys((Set<String>) set);
}
static public Enumeration<?> sortKeys(Set<String> keySet) {
    List<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedList.addAll(keySet);
    Collections.sort(sortedList);
    return Collections.enumeration(sortedList);
}
```

and override stringPropertyNames() method for save sorted properties in xml file:

```
@Override
public Set<String> stringPropertyNames() {
Set<String> tmpSet = new TreeSet<String>();
for (Object key : keySet())
{
    tmpSet.add(key.toString());
}
    return tmpSet;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did by overriding *method* store, like this:

```
@Override
public void store(Writer writer, String comments) throws IOException {

    this.keySet().stream().map(k -> (String)k).sorted().forEach(k -> {
        try {
            writer.append(String.format("%s=%s\n", k, get(k)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

Previous answers hadn't fit well for me.

Comment: This one was the only one working for me as well with Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, inspired of [smillien62's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127284/1166992):

```
final Properties properties = new Properties()
{
  private boolean recurse;

  @Override
  public synchronized Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet()
  {
    if (this.recurse)
    {
      return super.entrySet();
    }
    else
    {
      this.recurse = true;
      final TreeMap<Object, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(this);
      final Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entries = treeMap.entrySet();
      this.recurse = false;
      return entries;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a TreeMap (that sorts the key in natural order) and StringBuilder (we can use sysout also, but it is easy to log(slf4j) the return value)

```
public static String getPrettyPrintProps(Properties properties) {
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap(properties);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
map.forEach((k, v) -> sb.append("\n" + k + ":" + v ) );
return  sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    System.getProperties().entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getKey().toString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution is to do read, sort, write afterwards every time. Depending on your usecase this might be the simplest solution without the need of extending "Properties".

As I purely do the sorting of the lines all semantics like escaping etc is untouched. As "#" will automatically be on the top with default String sorting.

Of course you can use your favorite FileIO library to do the same. I use java.nio.file.Files here as an example.

```
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(propertiesFile, CHARSET).stream().sorted().toList();

  Files.write(propertiesFileFile, lines, CHARSET, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```