# Pulling values from a Properties file in order?

Tags: java, properties, configuration

I know the question may be duplicate [old_question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312383/pulling-values-from-a-java-properties-file-in-order)
 but it is very old.

How to read/parse Properties file in order?

It is necessary for my application to get the properties in the same order they written in the file?

Comment: Can you say why?

Comment: if there is a new simple solution

Comment: There isn't.  java.util.Properties is based on a Hashtable which doesn't guarantee sort order. That won't likely will never change. Look at [answer 2 of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275862/how-to-sort-properties-in-java) if you want a "fresh" answer.